# How to display multiple rows and columns from database into tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sqlite

I'm trying to display rows and columns from database into tableview. My approach is: First I will get data from database and then I will assign SQL statements into variables like this:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)arrayOfInquiries
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = @"select * from inquiry_tb";
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                               query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                Inquiry *voucher = [[Inquiry alloc]init];

                NSNumber *id = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1)];
                NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                              (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                NSString *date = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                NSString *branch = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];

                NSMutableDictionary *inquiries = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKeys:id,@"id",name,@"name",date,@"date",branch,@"branch",nil];
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
            return inquiries;
            }
         }
      }
    return nil;
}
```

And Im planning to return in to main view controller.

My question is: How can I return it to the main view controller. So that I can use it for the labels in the tableViewCell.

Is my approach right? Or is there much better approach?

Comment: I am not sure about SQLite database approach to say this is correct or not. You can implement a delegate and your MainViewController can implement the same. From this API you can return the inquiries to MainViewCOntrollerDelegate. But with this approach, your MainViewController should already be in memory to receive this delegate method.

Comment: One more suggestion.. If you use CoreData it has NSFetchedResultsViewController which will display contents in tableview manner and all edit operations in database will be in sync with your tableview.

Answer (score 0):

@teach Yes you can do it.

Create NSMutableArray in your main view controller(.H).Suppose you have

```
NSMutableArray *id1,*name1,*date1,*branch1;
```

now you can add it in your sql variables like this

```
NSString *querySQL = @"select *yourcolumnnames from inquiry_tb where=?";

NSNumber *id = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)];

   [id1 addObject:id];

            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
       [name1 addObject:name];

            NSString *date = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                            (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
       [date1 addObject:date];

            NSString *branch = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                            (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,3 )];

             [branch1 addObject:branch];
```

after that you can add your NSMutableArray *id1,*name1,*date1,*branch1; in your UITableViewcell and show the NSMutableArray.

Before the property has to assign(.H)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UILabel *id1label;
```

Now in (.m)

```
id1label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
id1label.frame=CGRectMake(115, 5, 400, 50);    
id1label.font=[UIFont fontWithName: @"Neue Helvetica" size:14.0];
id1label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
id1label.numberOfLines=0;
id1label.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
NSArray *comment=[ youranotherNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
id1label.text=[comment objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubview:id1label];
```